# Match user input with string

Tags: android, string, android-edittext

this is more than likely a very simple thing to do so I apologise if it is, but I cannot seem to implement it.

I am trying to check what a user types into a editText field and compare it against a hard coded string.

Here is the string that I want to compare against -

```
OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point,"House Information",
"4 Bed w/ large garden\n2 minute walk from Town Centre\nSchools 5 minute walk\n€300,000");
```

Here is my editText field -

```
<!-- Number of rooms text field -->
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/numberRooms"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="No. of rooms"
    android:imeActionLabel="launch"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

I want to be able to check what the user types against the "4" in the string. Here is what I have attempted so far -

```
EditText numberOfRooms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberRooms);
if(overlayitem.equals(numberOfRooms.getText().toString()))
{
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
}
```

So basically I don't want to compare the whole string, I just want to compare what the user enters to the first character in the string, which in this case will always be a number.

Comment: Use substring to get a substring of the hardcoded string the length you want, then use startsWith to see if the other string starts with that string

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks for the reply. I'm not sure how to do what you suggested, as I have two strings within my overlayitem, the "House Information" part and then the "4 bed w/...." part, but I only want to check against the second string part. I don't no if I should have mentioned but there is multiple strings to check, overlayitem1, overlayitem2 etc but I imagine if I can get one working I could get the rest too.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
    String rooms = overlayitem.getSnippet().substring(0,2);
      rooms = rooms.trim();
    if(rooms.equals(numberOfRooms.getText().toString()))
    {
        //Do whatever you want
    }
```

Comment: no it doesn't work, the app is crashing when I enter 4. I have defined just inside my public class my button like so - `EditText numberOfRooms;` in case my main post was not clear.

Comment: I tried it again and no luck :(. Just to be sure, I have declared `EditText numberOfRooms;` inside my public class but my actual editText id for the user entry field is `numberRooms` , is this correct or should the EditText numberOfRooms in my public class be changed to EditText numberRooms?

Comment: Error you are getting is not related with the comparison of the two string I've try it works just fine.

Comment: I don't no what else could cause it because when I take out the comparison the app runs normally. It would hardly be that the user can choose a price also before they search could it? Even though I am not doing anything with it the price field..

Comment: I also thought I would need to use R.id.numberRooms to get the information that was entered into the numberRooms field in the XML file

Answer (score 0):

overlayitem is not a String.
You might want to compare `overlayitem.getTitle()` or `overlayitem.getSnippet()` instead:

```
overlayitem.getTitle().equals(numberOfRooms.getText().toString())
```

Comment: Do I not need to use something along the lines of `EditText numberOfRooms = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberRooms);` though to take what the user inputs?

Comment: Yes, what you did in that aspect is just fine. (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numberRooms).getText().toString().

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how to implement it properly to an IF statement. When I try to do - `EditText numberOfRooms = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.numberRooms).getText().toString();` I get an error on the .getText() saying method getText is undefined for the type view. Could you explain to me how it is implemented correctly?

Comment: Try: String numberOfRooms = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.numberRooms)).getText().toString();